# Get JSON Data from Cherrypy Server with jQuery/AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, json, cherrypy

and python/cherrypy server

```
@cherrypy.tools.json_out()
@cherrypy.tools.json_in()
def get_data(self):
    cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    datas = {"ABCDEF"}
    return datas
```

but I get a Internal Server Error (500), where is my mistake?
I get work to post data to server, but with getting data is my problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is in your fifth line of your second code block. Change

```
datas = {"ABCDEF"}
```

to something like

```
datas = { "somedata" : "ABCDEF"}
```

And if this is all of your cherrypy server code, you're not exposing your route. Then you have to add the

```
@cherrypy.expose
```

annotation. You can consult [the docs for this](http://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/exposing.html) as well.

Comment: thank you very much, whatever i forgot the line:@cherrypy.expose

Answer (score 0):

Your `datas` variable is a Python set, and those are not directly serialisable to JSON. Perhaps you meant to create a dictionary or list?

Comment: at the moment this was an example, because the variable should contains a value from sql query,that is executed before.